# Question about Engagement split - Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I would like to create a journey with 3 paths based on click engagement. There will be 3 static links in email. My question is what will be the best solution for that. Creating 3 times engagement split for click on one of those 3 links or maybe use decision split and do it the same way with alias as custom dynamic links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the links are static, the easiest solution in my opinion would be to use 3 engagements splits like you said.
[image]